# Server static images files on Lumen

Tags: lumen

`Lumen` handles requests by routing them.

How can I serve static image file instead of creating an API to access the images?

Not something like this:

```
public function viewFile($name){

    return response()->make(Storage::disk('public')->get($name), 200, [
        'Content-Type' => Storage::mimeType($name),
        'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; '.$name,
    ]);

}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify on what you want? Do you want a route to render an image?

Comment: no. not route, but like static web page serving by apache

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just put them all in a directory called static/ and then tweak your .htaccess file to not rewrite those URLs to lumen?